# Python Qt - How to insert items in Table widget from another Thread?

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I want to insert text items from a Worker Qthread to a QTableWidget UI in Main thread ?.

I want to know the Syntax to create the signal in Main thread , so I can insert the text as well as the row and column from Worker thread by sending via signal

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myclass2 = myclass2()
        self.myclass2.start()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))
        self.show()


class myclass2(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myclass2, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
            print(" in thread \n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know that you must use a signal, now the question is: *what data do you need to send?*, You can think that you should send the row, the column and the text, so the signal must send 2 whole and one string, then you connect it to a slot and in it you insert it as if the data was created in the main thread:

```
import sys
import time
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)

        self.myclass2 = myclass2()
        self.myclass2.new_signal.connect(self.some_function)
        self.myclass2.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int, str)
    def some_function(self, r, c, text):
        it = self.table.item(r, c)
        if it:
            it.setText(text)
        else:
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text)
            self.table.setItem(r, c, it)

class myclass2(QtCore.QThread):
    new_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int, str)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
            r = random.randint(0, 9)
            c = random.randint(0, 9)
            text = "some_text: {}".format(random.randint(0, 9))
            self.new_signal.emit(r, c, text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks , Exactly what I needed

Comment: @aditya Do you already know how to transmit data from a secondary thread? I think that with the example and the explanation it is no longer necessary to ask: *how to modify XXX of the GUI from another thread*.

Comment: Actually , I understood that we need to do it by signal just confused with the syntax.

Comment: @aditya What confuses you?

Comment: mostly the signal concepts how to pass the strings or integer data from one particular class to the object of other but with this example, I think I understood how I can create new signals and pass my data as per